# Python - Function that adjusts columns and colors cells in multiple spread sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

Hello everyone hope you all are doing well.

Currently, I have a project I am working on that deals with a lot of data and I'm creating numerous pandas DataFrames with all the data I have and trying to compile it all into an excel file with each DataFrame having its own excel sheet. What I want to do is create a function that automatically adds each sheet to the excel file, expands the columns in each sheet, and colors cells in each sheet accordingly.

For example...

sheet14 would look something like what is attached...

[image]

Each sheet looks just like this but could have various amounts of rows but always the same amount of columns.

What I want to do is color the cells of Col1 that have a length of 1 green, length of 3 yellow, length of 5 purple, and so on.

How am I able to do this? I am able to do this with one sheet easily but to automate it is tedious because the multiple sheets part is making it difficult for me since I never had to deal with that.

Just so you know, cycled_data_aggregate looks like,
[DataFrame, 'A', 'A']

It is a <class 'list'> which contains,
[<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>]

Thank you all so much if you help! Hope I explained everything well enough. If not just a general explanation would help as the code I made is pretty weird likely haha! :)

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Color, PatternFill, Font, Border, Side
import xlsxwriter
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell

out_path = "C:\\....\\....xlsx"
writer1 = pd.ExcelWriter(out_path)

def MultipleSheetAdder(cycled_data_aggregate, overwrite_sheet_name, true_false):
    #  If the function for cycled_data_aggregate returns None...
    if cycled_data_aggregate == None:
        return None

    #  The sheet's data
    cycled_data = cycled_data_aggregate[0]
    
    #  If you want to overwrite what the sheet name is called and not use the
    #  cycled_data_aggregate's returned data

    if true_false:
        sheet_name = overwrite_sheet_name
    else:
        sheet_name = cycled_data_aggregate[1]


    cycled_data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name)
    for column in cycled_data:
        column_length = max(cycled_data[column].astype(str).map(len).max(), len(column)) + 3
        col_idx = cycled_data.columns.get_loc(column)
        writer.sheets[sheet_name].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_length)

    #  Add section here to change colors of specific rows in the first two columns depending on what
    #  values they are.
    {INSERT CODE HERE}

    return None  # Does this function need to even return anything? 

MultipleSheetAdder(Function(raw_data), '', False)

writer1.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to add the colours is with conditional formatting. Here is an example based on your data:

```py
import pandas as pd


# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['1.2.4', '2.2', '1.2.2', '2', '1.7.4'],
                   'Col2': [200, 100, 130, 140, 300],
                   'Col3': ['Text 1', 'Text 2', 'Text 3', 'Text 4', 'Text 5']})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_conditional.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'green'})
format2 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'yellow'})
format3 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'purple'})


# Apply a conditional format to the cell range.
max_row = df.shape[0]
worksheet.conditional_format(1, 0, max_row, 0, {'type':     'formula',
                                                'criteria': '=LEN($A2)=1',
                                                'format':   format1})
worksheet.conditional_format(1, 0, max_row, 0, {'type':     'formula',
                                                'criteria': '=LEN($A2)=3',
                                                'format':   format2})
worksheet.conditional_format(1, 0, max_row, 0, {'type':     'formula',
                                                'criteria': '=LEN($A2)=5',
                                                'format':   format3})

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: This was perfect! Thank you so much!